# Pattern type is incompatible with expected type

Tags: scala

I have already read other related questions but I have not get my answer.

Code:

```
inputType.zip(inputColName).zipWithIndex.map {
  case (inputType, inputColName, idx) =>
    inputType match {
      case **DoubleType** => println("test1")
      case _ => println('test2 ')
    }
}
```

`DoubleType` Pattern type is incompatible with expected type. found DoubleType.type. Required:(DataType, String).

I tried two simplified versions and the syntax looks right.

```
List(1,2,3).zip(List(4,5,6)).map { case(a, b) => 
        a match {case 1 => println(s"First is $a, second is $b") 
                 case _ => println("test")}}
```

The following also works

```
inputType.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (inputType, idx) =>
    inputType match {
      case DoubleType => println("test1")
      case _ => println('test2 ')
    }
}
```

I do not understand why after `zip` is added, why I am having this pattern matching type error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed to *group* the `inputType` and `inputColName` as `tuple2`

```
inputType.zip(inputColName).zipWithIndex.map {
  case ((inputType, inputColName), idx) =>
    inputType match {
      case DoubleType => println("test1")
      case _ => println("test2")
    }
}
```

When you use `zip` as

```
inputType.zip(inputColName)
```

then *Scala compiler* will treat it as

```
List[(org.apache.spark.sql.types.NumericType with Product with Serializable, String)]
```

And when you add `.zipWithIndex` then *Scala compiler* will read it as

```
List[((org.apache.spark.sql.types.NumericType with Product with Serializable, String), Int)]
```

**The Issue**

When you define *case* as `case(inputType, inputColName, idx)` then *Scala compiler* would treat `inputType` as `(org.apache.spark.sql.types.NumericType with Product with Serializable, String)` and `inputColName` as `Int` of the `((org.apache.spark.sql.types.NumericType with Product with Serializable, String), Int)` *dataTypes* formed when you created `inputType.zip(inputColName).zipWithIndex`. So `idx` is never identified.

**Even if you do the following without `idx` then also its valid** (now that `inputType` of the `case` is treated as `(org.apache.spark.sql.types.NumericType with Product with Serializable, String)`)

```
inputType.zip(inputColName).zipWithIndex.map {
  case (inputType, inputColName) =>
    inputType match {
      case (DoubleType, "col1") => println("test1")
      case _ => println("test2")
    }
}
```

I hope the explanation is clear.

Comment: Awesome! How do you get the data type print out?

Comment: its the scala REPL. I just copy pasted. :)